# Query the closest pair of points in range

Tags: algorithm

Initially, we have set of n points in 1D dimension. We have to answer two types of query:

- U: insert a new point with the coordinate U to the set (the point could be duplicate)
- L R: Find the minimum difference between any two points in range L and R.

For example, we initially have a set of points like: [1,6,7,10]. If we answer the second query in range [5, 11], then the answer is 1 (we choose two points 6 and 7).

I couldn't come up with the solution until now. I appreciate all your help!!

Comment: Generally speaking, questions that involve update/range queries are solved using segment trees. You should have a look at that.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur not sure it would be useful in this particular case though

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yes, I have had a look at segment tree, but still unable to do it :(((

Comment: It's a bit unclear what 'the point could be duplicate` means. Should the algorithm ignore a duplicate when the same input value appears, or rather keep it and include it in its reponse? For example, returning value zero for input [1,3,3,5] and query [2,4], meaning 'two points at the same coordinate found'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the minimum distance can only exist between adjacent points, you could just calculate the distances between every point and the next one and take the minimum. Assuming, your points are stored sorted in an array, that would be a single pass over it.

Comment: Doing a single pass for each query is highly likely to time out.

Comment: ...as well as storing all points in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer of Sergej:

If you only have to treat these queries you can use instead of an array a linked list to avoid memory allocation problems during insertion. The rest of the operations wont be much affected in this case.

Comment: This method may or may not be appropriate, depending on the expected size of the task. Remember updating a growing sorted list costs O(length), so building a list costs O(length squared). This may be too much for a big input.

Comment: I agree linear data in this case might be problematic. It was just to extend the array proposal to try to improve it, less memory allocations with a linked list.